# CSS : How do I vertically-center align text in a div ? (or any other elements which is not a table)

Tags: css, html, center-align

To vertically-center align text in a table-cell, I use `vertical-align: middle` in the `td`.

But the above doesn't work with divs, spans, header and other non-table elements.  So how can I vertically-center align text in such elements ?

Comment: Look at this
http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities, each with it's advantages and drawbacks.

Here's a [good article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) by Douglas Heriot explaining 5 others methods, and comparing them.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single line of text, you can set the line height to be the same height as the element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following style :

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: table-cell;
        }
</style>
```

That way, you are "displaying" the `div` as a table-cell and since `vertical-align` works with table-cells, you're text will be center-vertically aligned.