# how do i align text vertically using CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style='height:200px;'>
SOME TEXT
</div>
```

how do i align "SOME TEXT" at the bottom of the div using CSS without padding?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326877?

Comment: @strager, it's not really a dupe. The techniques for placing content at the bottom of a container are sufficiently different than those for centring it vertically within its container that I consider them different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute easiest way, though not-exactly using your code example, would be:

```
div {height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffa;
    position: relative;
    }

div p   {position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
```

html

```
<div id="container">
<p>SOME TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Wrap your text in an element, anything from `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>`...whatever, and position that element at the bottom of its container.

Comment: IE 6 doesn't know how to handle absolutely positioned elements with both a left and a right declared (or both top and bottom).  Instead you'd need to do left:0; width:100%-ish

Comment: IE6 is crap. and it won't support MANY other things  in the web app thingy i'm making so...

Comment: @ricebowl: if my users are using IE6 then they probably don't have a clue how to use my app anyway... so...

Comment: That's a valid, and worthwhile, point, sir. I tend to agree; I just have an instinctive "think of the users!" in-built. Sometimes this is useful, other times...less so. Did the answer work out okay for you, then? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a simple way, at least not cross browser.
You can use the display: table; vertical-align: center;
You can use JS/ CSS expressions.
You can have another element inside the div, and position it absolute in relation to the div:

```
<div style='position:relative;'>
    <div style='position: absolute; bottom:0;>
            My Text
    </div>
</div>
```

But really, as much as I hate to say, Tables is the KISS here (**if** you need to veritcaly center it).

Answer (score 0):

TDs can vertically align text with vertical-align, but this does not work on DIVs. It is not considered good style to use tables to vertically align elements.

You cannot vertical-align text within DIVs with CSS. You can only use padding, margin, or absolute and fixed positioning to align an text vertically.

If you use absolute positioning well, you can vertically align the text by vertically aligning a container that the text is in. However, absolutely positioned elements do not take up "space" within their container, which means you have to set a margin or padding to offset that space in the container.

Eg:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <span id="text">Some text, Some text, Some text, </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#id {
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#text {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
# id{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:bottom;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flex, [supported in most recent browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
div {
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  
  /* Uncomment to align it horizontally */
  /* justify-content: center; */
}
```

```html
<div style='height:200px;'>
  SOME TEXT
</div>
```